# Display a value attribute instead id in backoffice product management

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I add an attribute in product management in the backoffice (dropdown list)and I want to show the value instead of id.

here is the solution now it works i updated it :)

Grid.phtml

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
        ...
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer'); //my add attribute
        ...
        }

        protected function _prepareColumns()
            {

// add this code
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
$values = array();
foreach ($options as $option){
    $values[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}

            $this->addColumn('manufacturer', //my add attribute
              array(
                    'header'=> 'Manufacturer',
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'index' => 'manufacturer',
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'options' => $values,
                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid::_prepareCollection() there are many attributes with addColumn.

You should customize the options index with the possible values.

There is a great tutorial in http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-adding-custom-attributes-to-the-backend-product-grid/

In resume you should use the following code.

```
protected function _getAttributeOptions($attribute_code)
{
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
    $options = array();
    foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option ) {
        $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }
    return $options;
}
```

And now lets update our addColumn functions to the following:

```
$this->addColumn('manufacturer', //my add attribute
  array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manufacturer'),
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'manufacturer',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'options' => $this->_getAttributeOptions('attribute_code'),
));
```

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't work, it still displays the id

Comment: i have found the solution now it works, thank you Rodrigo for your help

Answer (score 0):

For getting attribute just use

`$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer');`

instead of yours!